# How can I let some asyncio script go on scraping which currently gets stuck somewhere in it's execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio, semaphore

I've created a script using asyncio library to parse the name of different post owner from a webpage. The idea is to supply this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) within the script which parses all the links of different posts from each page and traverses next pages to do the same. However, the script then uses all the links within this function `fetch_again()` to reach the inner page in order to get the owner of all the posts.

Although I could have scraped the name of owners from it's landing page, I used the following approach only to know as to how I can achieve the same using the design I'm trying with. I've used `semaphore` within the script to limit the number of requests.

When I use the following script, I found it working for 100 or few more posts and then it gets stuck. It doesn't throw any error.

I've tried with:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def fetch(url):
    async with semaphore:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                text = await response.text()
                result = await processing_docs(session, text)
            return result

async def processing_docs(session, html):
    coros = []
    tree = fromstring(html)
    titles = [urljoin(link,title.attrib['href']) for title in tree.cssselect(".summary .question-hyperlink")]
    for title in titles:
        coros.append(fetch_again(session,title))

    next_page = tree.cssselect("div.pager a[rel='next']")
    if next_page:
        page_link = urljoin(link,next_page[0].attrib['href'])
        coros.append(fetch(page_link))
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)

async def fetch_again(session,url):
    async with semaphore:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            tree = fromstring(text)
            title = tree.cssselect("h1[itemprop='name'] a")[0].text
            print(title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncio.gather(*(fetch(url) for url in [link])))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    loop.close()
```

***How can I let the script go on parsing which currently gets stuck somewhere in it's execution?***

Comment: You need to debug _why_ your script gets stuck. I suspect that you have a deadlock: `fetch` acquires the semaphore and calls `processing_docs`, which recursively calls more instances of `fetch` and `fetch_again`. If the recursion in `fetch` reaches depth of 10, the innermost `fetch` will never acquire the semaphore because it is being held by its *callers*. I suggest that you replace recursion with an `asyncio.Queue`, and that you create a fixed number of workers that process the queue, and put more stuff in it. That way you don't even need a semaphore and you are guaranteed not to deadlock.

Comment: An even simpler option, that doesn't require refactoring, is to just move the recursive call `result = await processing_docs(session, text)` as well as `return result` outside the `async with` blocks, i.e. to call `processing_docs()` with the semaphore _released_. That should take care of the deadlock while still serving the purpose of limiting the number of concurrent connections.

Comment: You described it in the right way but it is my incapability that I might not have been able to bring about the change and that is the reason I still get the same behavior.  [This is](https://filebin.net/hxnlevm7sfh8aice) how I modified that portion @user4815162342.

Comment: I meant something like [this](https://pastebin.com/wSEgNmDc).

Comment: What an elegant fix!!! It perfectly did the trick. Would be glad if you post an answer so that I can accept it @user4815162342. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script likely blocks due to a *deadlock*: `fetch` acquires the semaphore and calls `processing_docs`, which recursively calls more instances of `fetch` and `fetch_again` *with the semaphore still held*. If the recursion depth of `fetch` reaches 10, the innermost `fetch` will never acquire the semaphore because it will have been acquired by its *callers*. I suggest that you replace recursion with an `asyncio.Queue`, and drain (and populate) the queue with a fixed number of worker tasks. That way you don't even need a semaphore and you are guaranteed not to deadlock.

An even simpler fix, which doesn't require refactoring, is to just move the recursive call to `processing_docs()` outside the `async with semaphore` block, i.e. to invoke `processing_docs()` with the semaphore released. After all, the purpose of the semaphore is to limit concurrent access to the remote server, not local processing which is not concurrent in the first place as asyncio is single-threaded. That should eliminate the deadlock while still limiting the number of concurrent connections:

```
async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with semaphore:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                text = await response.text()
        result = await processing_docs(session, text)
        return result
```

Also note that you should probably create a single session in a top-level coroutine and propagate it throughout the code. You are already doing that between `fetch`, `processing_docs` and `fetch_again`, but you could also do it for the top-level calls to `fetch`.